How do you chain selectinload() in a loop using sqlalchemy query?
Take this query for example:
statement = select(Parent)
  .filter(Parent.id == parent_id)
  .options(selectinload(Parent.child).
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
           .selectinload(Child.nodes)
  )
result = await async_session.execute(statement)

parent = result.scalars().first()

You can see that I'm doing .selectinload().selectinload().selectinload().  If I needed to do that 10 times, how can I add those in a loop so I don't have to write it 10 times? I have a self-referential 1 to many relationship that can go down many, many levels.  I have a function that will tell me the depth I need to go.  So if that function tells me I need to go 6 levels down, I want to create a for loop that will chain selectinload 6 times. If I only use a single selectinload it will only give me 1 level deep of the data.
I already have the ability to loop through adding .options() like this:
    select_options = [
        selectinload(Parent.attr1),
        selectinload(Parent.attr2),
        selectinload(Parent.child).selectinload(Child.nodes).selectinload(Child.nodes),
      ]
    query = select(Model)
    query = query.filter(Model.id == model_id)
    for option in select_options:
      query = query.options(option)

    result = await async_session.execute(query)

But that is only for .options().  I'd like a way to then add a chain of .selectinload() within the .options like in my first example.
Thanks
Jon
SQLAlchemy 2.0.36
asyncpg 0.30.0
fastapi 0.112.0


Would something like clause = selectinload(Parent.child), for _ in range(3): clause = clause.selectinload(Child.nodes), .... .options(clause) work?

@MatsLindh That worked!!  Just what I needed.  Thanks
